# CDCL and Conflict Clauses

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am wondering if conflict clauses generated by running the CDCL algorithm can be resolved. In running the CDCL algorithm, I generated a conflict clause $\neg x \lor \neg y$ and $x \lor \neg y$.

Before backtracking, can I resolve the conflict clauses to resolve $x$ such that I am left with $\neg y$, which is unary?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the CDCL algorithm?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Conflict-Driven Clause Learning